# Сохранение таблицы в Java без использование БД

Tags: java

Сохранение таблицы в Java без использование БД. 
Нужно вот примерно вот такую таблицу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно сохранять определённую строчку, и добавлять строчки, и получать строчки по `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял- вы хотите в памяти хранить список ключ-значение, для этого  используйте `Map<String, Integer>`

Comment: А если можно будет Map сохранить как файл, а так пойдёт

Comment: Сохранить в файл можно любые данные какие вам надо, только надо описать в какой файл и в каком виде

Comment: @Redis Сохрани в файл json

Comment: @FarizMamedow Если бы не надо было бы качать д.п. бибилотеки

Comment: А в чем сложность то? Делаете обход мапа, собираете строку и выводите ее в файл.